# Visual Studio Source Control recovering undone pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

Yup, I'm that idiot.  But I did *select only the files I wanted to undo* in the Pending Changes panel.  It opened a new dialog, which I wrongfully assumed only contained the selection I made in the main panel.  I said to undo everything and presto! a bunch of stuff I didn't want to undo was undone (much like the sweater song.  I'm a tool).  So my question is: is there anyway to recover the work that I undid?

Comment: and which version control tool are you using ? TFS, SVN .. ?

Comment: sorry if I not understand that correctly ;) but you have made changes and these changes are not checked in right? and you want to recover to that state before you made these changes?

Comment: The changes were undone so it reverted back to the version in source control, overwriting the changed files I had in my local project.

Comment: I also run a local git for two reasons 1) it provides a safety net for my occasional stupidities like this one and 2) I can use git tools to see the full breadth of changes I made or just got from getting latest (was using inbuilt git GUI, now very happy with SourceTree)

Comment: I, also, am that idiot.

Comment: This has happened to me twice with 2015+Git. Undoing a project or solution change seems to have the effect of undoing ALL the changes - even the prompt says "undo 1 file:". Lucky i had a dll i could pull changes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Unless you did this while the project was open in VS.  If it was then you should have been given a dialog asking if you wanted to reload the file (which was changed outside the IDE).  You then could have said "No" and re-saved your changes.

Otherwise, as far as I'm aware, it will have been overwritten (so you can't even undelete).

Also, not directly related to the question, but [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/080540cb-e35f-4651-b71c-86c73e4a633d/) has saved my bacon once or twice.  You do pay for it in load speed though!

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the honest truth.  Luckily I didn't lose that much and I've about got it back to where it was.  I've been using source control for a while, so I don't know what I was thinking. I'll just have to be more careful next time around :).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Is this something that has to be implemented on the server or just on my machine?

Comment: Just your machine - find it in the gallery

Answer (score 6):

I did exactly same thing. Fortunately I had realized that before I rebuilt the project. I used Telerik JustDecompile to get my lost code from the assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your tip about Telerik JD saved my bacon! The generated code wasn't 100% perfect, but I was able to make it work. (Note to self: ALWAYS shelve or check in code at the end of each day!)

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to have been viewing your work in the browser via live-server or the like, and you haven't closed the page, you can right click and view the source. This will get your html changes back at least.